# ES6 Optional parameters and default values: are these interface or implementation details?

Tags: javascript, interface, ecmascript-6, jsdoc, implements

In ES6/ES2015, using interfaces and implementations (`@interface` and `@implements`),

***Is specifying that a parameter is optional part of the interface or the implementation?***

***If part of the interface, what about specifying the default value for the optional parameter?***

- In Scenario A, transpiling to ES5 with JSCompiler will object to the interface for `otherMethod` with `ERROR - interface member functions must have an empty body` (i.e. that the default value is syntactic sugar for preface code that sets a parameter's value when the value is undefined)

***Are the answers the same whether ES5 or ES6?***

**Scenario A**

```
/**
 * @interface
 */
class SomeInterface {
  /**
   * @param (boolean=) someArgument
   */
  someMethod(someArgument) {}

  /**
   * @param (boolean=) someArgument
   */
  otherMethod(someArgument = false) {}
}


/**
 * @implements {SomeInterface}
 */
class SomeImplementation {

  /** @override */
  someMethod(someArgument = false) {
    // do something
  }

  /** @override */
  otherMethod(someArgument = false) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

**Scenario B**

```
/**
 * @interface
 */
class SomeInterface {
  /**
   * @param (boolean) someArgument
   */
  someMethod(someArgument) {}
}

/**
 * @implements {SomeInterface}
 */
class SomeImplementation {

  /**
   * @param (boolean=) someArgument
   * @override
   */
  someMethod(someArgument = false) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Is specifying that a parameter is optional part of the interface or the implementation?"* Certainly the interface. The caller, who implements against the interface has to know whether it does or does not have to pass the argument.